# How do I make a JavaScript array that has properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

The [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function [returns something that looks like a hybrid array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Creating_an_array_using_the_result_of_a_match). It's an array, but it has properties.

```js
console.log(/d(b+)(d)/i.exec("cdbBdbsbz"));
// => ["dbBd", "bB", "d", index: 1, input: "cdbBdbsbz"]
```

I can call `result[0]`, `result[1]`, `result.index`, `result.input`, etc.

How do I make my own?

`[0, 1, "a": 1]` is obviously a syntax error, and `{"0": 1, "1": 1, "a": 1}` *does* give me an object I can index and access properties of, however it's not *the same* as what's returned by `exec`.

I tried doing it with `__proto__`:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.__proto__.a = 1 // arr.a is 1 now
```

But `console.log` doesn't display the property like it does when run on the result of `exec`, so I suspect it's *still* not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy enough - an array in javascript is just an object, and you can attach any properties you like to it:

```
var test = ["foo","bar","baz"];
test.index = 1;
test.input="foobarbaz";
console.log(test);
```

That `console.log` looks identical to the one returned by `regex.exec`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/9rCmJ/

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
var arr = [0, 1];
arr.a = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

An array is also an object, so you can set property directly:

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b'];
console.log(typeof myArray); // 'object'
myArray.say = 'hi';
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it in two steps:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.test = "Hello world";
```